# Cypress: intercept a network request with compression-type gzip to simulate mapbox

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cypress, vuejs3, mapbox-gl-js

I am currently having trouble with mocking a particular request [mapbox-gl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-gl) is making. When the map is loaded from mapbox pbf-files are being requested and i have not been able to mock this.

My guess is that the core issue is that there seems to be an open bug with cypress [issue-16420](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/16420).

I tried alot of different intercept variants. I tried all kinds of response headers. I gziped, compressed, brd the file that I serve via fixture. I tried different encodings for the fixture. Nothing worked. One of the interceptors looks basically like this

```
 cy.intercept({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '**/fonts/v1/mapbox/DIN%20Offc%20Pro%20Italic,Arial%20Unicode%20MS%20Regular/0-255.pbf?*',
  }, {
    fixture: 'fonts/italic.arial.0-255.pbf,binary',
    statusCode: 204,
    headers: {
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5',
      'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Link',
      'age': '11631145',
      'cache-control': 'max-age=31536000',
      'content-encoding': 'compress',
      'content-type': 'application/x-protobuf',
      'date': 'Sat, 19 Feb 2022 20:46:43 GMT',
      'etag': 'W/"b040-+eCb/OHkPqToOcONTDlvpCrjmvs"',
      'via': '1.1 4dd80d99fd5d0f6baaaf5179cd921f72.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
      'x-amz-cf-id': '4uY9rjBgR_R12nkfHFrBMLEpNuWygW9DkmODlMEzwJHABTGCGg8pww==',
      'x-amz-cf-pop': 'FRA56-P7',
      'x-cache': 'Hit from cloudfront',
      'x-origin': 'Mbx-Fonts'
    }
  }).as('get.0-255.pbf').as('getItalicArial0-255');
```

Now even if this is a bug there has to be some kind of workaround to serve the file in a cypress test without having an active internet connection. It would be great not having to rely on the network on tests. So all kinds of workarounds and dirty tricks are welcome in making this intercept work.